How to add/fix these bootstrap dependencies for this project?
I am working on a team Capstone from a Boot-camp. After cloning it to a new Linux machine, the project fails to install the dependencies for this project. How do I install these certain dependencies so my project run npm run dev?
Terminal error message
ding@ding-Inspiron-7573: e $ npm install
HT WARN inflight@l.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async request
y a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.

npm glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead

npm @humanwhocodes/config-array@®.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead

npm bootstrap-vue-3@0.3.12: This package is deprecated and the repo was moved to bootstrap-vue organization. For updates on this project go to bootstrap-vue. The
package is called bootstrap-vue-next. Thanks for your support!

[sJUMWARN vue@2.7.16: Vue 2 has reached EOL and is no longer actively maintained. See https://v2.vuejs.org/eol/ for more details.

[JuMWARN popper.js@l.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy vl

added 271 packages, and audited 272 packages in 29s

99 packages are looking for funding
run “npm fund® for details

2 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run “npm audit’ for details.
ding@ding-Inspiron-7573: $ npm audit
# npm audit report

bootstrap 4.0.0 - 4.6.2
Severity: moderate
Bootstrap Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-vc8w-jrov-vj7f
fix available via "npm audit fix --force’
Will install bootstrap-vue@l.5.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/bootstrap-vue/node_modules/bootstrap

bootstrap-vue 0.5.1 - 0.10.1 || >=2.0.0-rc.0

Depends on vulnerable versions of bootstrap

node_modules/bootstrap-vue

2 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force


This is the pack JSON file
package.JSON file
{
  "name": "final-vue-capstone-seed",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "prepreview": "npm run build",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "axios": "^1.6",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "bootstrap-vue-3": "^0.3.12",
    "e": "^0.2.33",
    "v-calendar": "^3.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.1",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.20.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "vite": "^3.2.7",
    "vue": "^3.2.45",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^9.3.0"
  }
}

I have tried npm install --savedev "bootstrap-vue@1.5.1 to install the dependencies but it failed.
It then asks to install other dependencies with npm install --legacy-peer-deps but that fails as well, leading the message back to install "bootstrap-vue@1.5.1" again.
bootstrap error
ding@ding-Inspiron-7573:~/Project/Medical-App/vue$ npm install --savedev "bootstrap-vue@1.5.1"
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: final-vue-capstone-seed@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.4.38
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   dev vue@"^3.2.45" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^2.4.2" from bootstrap-vue@1.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/bootstrap-vue
npm ERR!   bootstrap-vue@"1.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/ding/.npm/_logs/2024-08-30T19_14_50_801Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/ding/.npm/_logs/2024-08-30T19_14_50_801Z-debug-0.log



It suceeded before. The npm audit fails because there's a CVE. But the deps were working the first time after npm install. If you want to fix the cve looks like you'll need to move to  the alternative as appears in the output This package is deprecated and the repo was moved to bootstrap-vue organization. For updates on this project go to bootstrap-vue. The package is called bootstrap-vue-next  so you have sensible dependency ranges

It turns out, npm run dev can still be run. This version of Bootstrap has web vulnerabilities so it needs to be updated to prevent it but nothing is broken. So for personal projects, the warnings can be ignored but the project can be hacked if sent into production.
